# Free server sellection for react project

Tags: mysql, postgresql, server

I am working on a project and developing with react. I need somewhere to keep my datas. Where do you suggest? I use json-server while I'm following my course. But I'm open for any suggestion. Ofcourse it would be better if it is free at least while working on prototype.
What about mysql, nosql or postgresql? Probably I choose postgre because of it's support which comes with it's popularity

Answer (score 0):

I have used [Heroku](https://www.heroku.com/) to deploy production applications and hobby projects. It has a free tier, and it is fast and easy to setup. Databases are supported via [addons](https://elements.heroku.com/addons) (including [Postgres](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/heroku-postgresql)), some of which have free tiers. Heroku recognizes many applications automatically, but if are using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app), you need to use a [buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/apoorvparijat/create-react-app-buildpack) for the deployment.